# How to set a radio button in Android

Tags: android, radio-button

I have an app that uses radio buttons. The default for this button is set in the main.xml file, ie:

```
android:id="@+id/rb_sat1E"
android:checked="true"
```

In the Java file I have:

```
final RadioButton radio1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb_sat1E);
```

I have also created a 'Reset' button in the main Java file and can use the following code to reset TextView information ie.

```
pos1_deg.setText("0.0");
```

But how do I reset a radio button? I would have thought it to be something like

```
radio1.setBoolean("TRUE");
```

But that does not work at all.

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

For radioButton use

```
radio1.setChecked(true);
```

It does not make sense to have just one RadioButton. If you have more of them you need to uncheck others through

```
radio2.setChecked(false); ...
```

If your setting is just on/off use CheckBox.

Comment: For other readers who may find themselves in my position: setChecked (true), is COMPLETELY DIFFERENT from setSelected (true).  Ack.

Comment: This doesn't work if radio buttons placed in  radio group so use answer given by gulchrider

Answer (score 108):

If you want to do it in code, you can call the check member of RadioGroup:

```
radioGroup.check(R.id.radioButtonId);
```

This will check the button you specify and uncheck the others.

Comment: Thanks :) This is the better answer for me; exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: radioGroup.check(radioGroup.getChildAt(0).getId()); - to check first item on list

Comment: I agree. Please do that.

Answer (score 34):

Or you can do it in the XML file :

In the **RadioGroup** using : `android:checkedButton="id_button_to_check"`

or in the **RadioButton** : `android:checked="true"`

Comment: When I check radiobutton in xml, I cant uncheck it later. It's like that radiobutton is removed from the group

Comment: sorry that I'm late, but this is the intended behaviour for radiobuttons. When you select it, you can't unselect it EXCEPT by selecting another radio button in the radiogroup

Comment: we can clear the selection by calling check(-1) or clearCheck().

Answer (score 13):

Just to clarify this: if we have a `RadioGroup` with several `RadioButtons` and need to activate one by index, implies that:

```
radioGroup.check(R.id.radioButtonId)
```

and

```
radioGroup.getChildAt(index)`
```

We can to do:

```
radioGroup.check(radioGroup.getChildAt(index).getId());
```

Answer (score 5):

if you have done the design in XML and want to show one of the checkbox in the group as checked when loading the page below solutions can help you

```
    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtLastNameSignUp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup">
<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="true"
    android:id="@+id/Male"
    android:text="Male"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Female"
            android:text="Female"/>
        </RadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 3):

Many times if your radio buttons belong to the same radioGroup then

**radioButton.setChecked(true)**

will not select the radio button properly. So to solve this problem try using your radioGroup.

**radioGroup.check(R.id.radioButtonId)**

Answer (score 2):

Use this code

```
    ((RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio3)).setChecked(true);
```

mistake -> don't forget to give () for whole before setChecked()
-> If u forget to do that setChecked() is not available for this radio button

Answer (score 0):

I have multiple RadioButtons without Group and `setChecked(true)` works, but `setChecked(false)` don't works. But this code works:

```
RadioButton switcher = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.active);
                        switcher.setOnClickListener(new RadioButton.OnClickListener(){
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                if(((RadioButton)v).isSelected()){
                                    ((RadioButton)v).setChecked(false);
                                    ((RadioButton)v).setSelected(false);
                                } else {
                                    ((RadioButton)v).setChecked(true);
                                    ((RadioButton)v).setSelected(true);
                                }
                            }

                        });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
btnDisplay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

            // get selected radio button from radioGroup
        int selectedId = radioSexGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

        // find the radiobutton by returned id
            radioSexButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);

        Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this,
            radioSexButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

});
```

Comment: Can you please explain why OP should use your code?