# Android: onResume update Radio button

Tags: android, user-interface, radio-button, onresume

I have a number of radio buttons on my menu. However, whenever onResume() is called, I found that it will reset all the radio buttons values to default. What I can do to keep it maintained to the previous status?

***Update
I know the status of the buttons. However, they are reset. I wanna find way to manually reset them. However, I found that I used the code

```
 getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
```

to try to get the menu and hence the MenuItem caused NullPointerException at the method onResume(). How can I get the menu and hence set the menuItems?

Comment: You must save it to your instance.

Answer (score 2):

As soon as the [user clicks on the `radioButton`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323778/how-to-set-onclicklistener-on-a-radiobutton-in-android), save its identifier/ID to your local storage.
 (example: [`sharedPreferences`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)). And on the activity `onResume()`, check if there's any saved status of clicked `radioButton`, and [set it clicked.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134582/how-to-set-a-radio-button-in-android)

Links provided for your reference.


*I didn't provide a code because you also didn't provide any codes.*

Comment: I have saved that and know that should be on or off. but i cannot get the MenuItem to reset it. Updated the question again for clarification

Comment: I don't actually get your updated question, it is reset and you want to manually reset it? Do you mean to `setCheck` the `radioButton`?