# How to set the (checked) state of a radiobutton programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, android-radiobutton

I have a wireless device with a valve connected to an Android App over Bluetooth LE.  In the App I have an activity layout with 2 radioButtons in a radioGroup.  On startup, I need to query the external device to determine the current status of the valve and set a radioButton in the App accordingly.  My basic strategy is as follows...

```
private RadioGroup valveStateRadioGroup;
private RadioButton valveOnRadioButton;
private RadioButton valveOffRadioButton;

static boolean valveOn = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // set view and init Bluetooth stuff here

    valveStateRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.valve_State_Radio_Group);
    valveOnRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.valve_on_radioButton);
    valveOffRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.valve_off_radioButton);

    valveStateRadioGroup.clearCheck();

    valveStateRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                // do normal radioButton CLICKED stuff here
        }
    });
    queryValveState(); // call coms routine to get initial device status
}

public void queryValveState() {
    // code here that sends out a wireless query to the device
}

@Override
public synchronized void onDataAvailable(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
    //reply received from device, parse packet, determine valve status
    valveOn = false; // based on reply from device
    refeshUi();
}

private void refeshUi() {
    if (valveOn) {
        valveOnRadioButton.setChecked(true);
    }
    else {
        valveOffRadioButton.setChecked(true); // <<<<<<<<<<<< THIS is the problem
}
```

The problem I'm having is that when valveOffRadioButton.setChecked(true) fires, it never in turn fires OnCheckedChangeListener nor updates the Widget in the UI. I am able to set the state of the radioButton if I do it in onCreate().  I guess my actual question is... How do you set a radioButton in a routine outside of onCreate()?

Comment: take a look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134582/how-to-set-a-radio-button-in-android

Comment: Seems what you have is a RadioButtonGroup, I think you will need to change the state to the radio group instead of the individual Radio Button. Check this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/37100605/3792636

Comment: The problem might be a different thread, try to update using runOnUIThread inside refeshUi().

Comment: Thanks  Muthukrishnan Rajendran.  Worked perfectly!  Still learning... ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Muthukrishnan Rajendran for the answer...

```
private void refeshUi() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (valveOn) {
                valveOnRadioButton.setChecked(true);
            }
            else {
                valveOffRadioButton.setChecked(true);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

valveOnRadioButton.setChecked(true);

Answer (score 1):

Late for the answer, but this work for me:

((RadioButton)radioGroup.getChildAt(0)).setChecked(true);

Regards